# How to get access to the fields of custom adapter in ListView in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

In my project I use a custom adapter to define the items of a ListView. So I want to define special behavior of item in ListView, which will be depend on the value of the field in adapter. Like this :

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}
```

So, here, in this method I want to get access to the element of adapter to get the value from it, number of which is defined by the int position. So, what is code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are defining an custom adapter you can save a reference to the adapter in the activity that registers the onClick behaviour. You now can call [getItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29) on the Adapter, if you have implemented the getItem method properly.

Comment: So I've coded

    l.getAdapter().getItem(position)

but what's next - I want to get item and perform it my own item's type something like that:

 (TypeItemListView) l.getAdapter().getItem(position). ---> here can I access to the fields of custom class fro adapter?

Comment: Save a reference to the ArrayAdapter<TypeItemListView> that you are creating to populate your list. In that way you will get back the right kind of object if you call apater.getItem(). After that you can do whatever you want with the item.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply cast it if you're confident enough it is always your adapter that is used:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    ((MyAdapter) l.getAdapter()).myMethod(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected item(object) from list. Lets say your custom adapter containing Restaurent object per row, and your listView name foodJntListView, then

```
Restaurent rest= (Restaurent) foodJntListView.getSelectedItem();
```

will give you the selected item(object).